# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi drops MacBook Pro 9,2

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro 9,2 (dual boot with rEFInd) and I'm experiencing constant drops of my WiFi signal.

I followed the instructions listed here [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) to install drivers. I had to install linux-firmware-nonfree and firmware-b43-installer. My network issues persisted and I followed the debugging instructions on this page. It suggested that I ignore IPv6 so I did that but it doesn't help. I've been Googling for a few hours but nothing seems to work.

I ran the wireless script and [here are the results](https://gist.github.com/Roemerb/2c7ce7c4e1b84909f341).

Comment: Are you certain there ain't any open issues for your hardware and it's supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami I've looked for it quite a lot but cannot find a solution for my particular model

Comment: does this occur only on battery? if so, try `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`, which should disable power management for the wlan0 adapter.

Comment: @sostacked Oh hey you may actually be right. I'll try it later. I mainly use OS X again but thanks for the help!